# I want to do insert in salesforce only if external id is not present in salesforce

Tags: apex, integration, json

I have a below json response

```
{"notes":[{"noteID":2649475,"requestID":407414,"noteDate":"2020-12-29T06:00:28.0000000+00:00","note":"This request was sent by email. We will allow 48 hours before following up on receipt of the request."},{"noteID":2654630,"requestID":407414,"noteDate":"2020-12-30T00:00:00.0000000+00:00","note":"I called to verify receipt of the request for Medical Records and Itemize}]}
```

I want to do insertion only if noteID is not present in salesforce. I dont want to do upsert operation. NoteId is external id

Below is my code

```
            Httpresponse res = XeBeeWebserviceController.authenticate();
            if(res!=null)
            {
                string body= '{ "RequestIDs": " '  +RID+ ' "}';
                
                // Instantiate a new http object
                Http h = new Http();
                
                // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                req.setEndpoint(GET_BY_REQUESTLIST);
                req.setMethod('POST');
                req.setHeader( 'Cookie', res.getHeader('Set-Cookie'));
                req.setBody(body);
                req.setHeader( 'User-Agent', 'Fiddler');
                req.setHeader('Host', 'app.xebee.com');
                req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                req.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length()+'');
                req.setTimeOut(120000);
                // Send the request, and return a response
                res = h.send(req);
                
                System.debug('body'+res.getBody());
                
                if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
                NotesDeserializeJsonToAPex jsonResponse= NotesDeserializeJsonToAPex.parse(res.getBody());
                system.debug('size'+totalNotes.size());
                system.debug('size'+jsonResponse.Notes);
                system.debug('size'+jsonResponse.notes.size());
                Map<String,XB_Note__c> mapNoteIdWithNote= new Map<String,XB_Note__c>();
                    if(existingNotesList!=null && !existingNotesList.isEmpty())
                    {
                    for(XB_Note__c note: existingNotesList)
                    {
                       mapNoteIdWithNote.put(note.Note_ID__c,note);
                    }
                    }
                    Integer i=0;
                        for(Object note: jsonResponse.Notes)
                        {
                            XB_Note__c xb=mapNoteIdWithNote.get(jsonResponse.notes[i].noteID);
                            if(xb==null)
                            {
                               XB_Note__c n=new XB_Note__c();
                               n.Content__c=jsonResponse.notes[i].note ;
                               n.Note_ID__c=jsonResponse.notes[i].noteID ;
                               n.Medical__c=mapRequestId.get(jsonResponse.notes[i].requestID);
                               n.Type__c='From XB';
                               notesList.add(n);
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                
             }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Right now, your post contains an objective and some code, but doesn't contain a question. Please [edit] your post to ask a single, specific, detailed question about the work you've done or an issue you are facing. You can learn more about our format at [ask] and [On Topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My issue is when I am running batch for some records multiple notes are creating

Comment: **Please [edit] your post** to describe your specific issue, and include a minimal example of the code to reproduce it. Please do not post comments to add information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query just the existing notes that you care about before determining if the note already existed. In addition, if there are duplicates in the list, you need to check for that, too. Here's a corrected version based on my [Aggregate-Query-Update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html), which you may want to read about, as you'll be using it a lot if you write any significant amount of Apex code.

```
// Aggregate: Identify notes we need to query
Set<String> noteIds = new Set<String>();
for(NotesDeserializeJsonToApex.Note noteItem: jsonResponse.Notes) {
    noteIds.add(noteItem.noteId+'');
}
// Query: Remove existing items from Set
for(XB_Note__c record: [SELECT Note_ID__c FROM XB_Note__c WHERE Note_ID__c = :noteIds]) {
    noteIds.remove(record.Note_ID__c+'');
}
// Update the database with new records
for(NotesDeserializeJsonToApex.Note noteItem: jsonResponse.Notes) {
    // When add returns true, set was modified (so note id did not already exist)
    if(noteIds.add(noteItem.noteId+'')) {
        notesList.add(
            new XB_Note__c(
                Content__c=noteItem.Note, 
                Note_ID__c=noteItem.noteId, 
                Medical__c=mapRequestId.get(noteItem.requestID), 
                Type__c='From XB'
            )
        );
    }
}
insert notesList;
```